# How do I refer to an object created in a "with" statement?

Tags: delphi, with-statement

I'm creating nested components at run time. How can I assign the `Parent` property of a child component inside a `with`?

```
with Tspanel.Create(categorypanel) do
begin
  parent:=categorypanel;  // categorypanel, is a declared variable
  height:=30;
  visible:=true;

  button1 := tsbutton.Create();
  // Here is my problem! I want the parent to be the
  // panel I've created with the "with tspanel.create(...)"
  button1.Parent := ...
end;
```

My goal is to not declare variables for every component.

Comment: 'My goal is to not declare variables for every component' - why ever not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do what you want with a `with` statement. There is no way to name the object that is the subject of a with statement.

Use a local variable instead. For example:

```
var
  Panel1: TPanel
  Button1: TButton;
....
Panel1 := TPanel.Create(Form1);
Panel1.Parent := Form1;
Button1 := TButton.Create(Panel1);
Button1.Parent := Panel1;
```

As an added benefit you get to remove these `with` statements that are a scoping blight on any code.

Comment: "With" is rarely worthwhile. More trouble than it's worth.

Comment: ... and you will be able to debug the named object in the IDE.